# Oracle sql creating a trigger to work out company worked overtime hours?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

So I have the following tables here in an oracle database, regarding the company Funtom:

```
Funtom_employee

emp_ID
Emp_firstname
Emp_surname
Emp_department
emp_street
emp_town
emp_district
Emp_grade
Emp_site
Employee_status
Employee_termination
Employee_start

Funtom_grade

Grade_ID
Grade_rate
Grade_hours

Funtom_timesheet

Timesheet_ID
Timesheet_emp
Timesheet_wc
Timesheet_hours
Timesheet_OT
Timesheet_approved
```

When a user inserts data about an employee's weekly work into Funtom_timesheet, he inserts into the attributes Timesheet_emp, Timesheet_hours and Timesheet_wc (week commencing).

However the timesheet_hours inserted includes both normal contracted hours and overtime hours worked as well. The table Funtom_timesheet contains the attribute Timesheet_OT which needs filling in also.

Each employee has it's own grade which dictates how many hours are contracted to an employee (normal hours) which is found in the table Funtom_grade.

I need to create a trigger which automatically generates the amount of hours that were overtime by garbbing the user inserted total hours and taking away the amount of hours that were contracted to the employee (normal hours) found in the table Funtom_grade.

Could anyone be as awesome as to create their own way on how to do this for me?

I have my following version so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_timesheet_hours
AFTER UPDATE ON Funtom_timesheet 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
V_contracted_hours number;
V_OT_hours number;
V_normal_hours;
V_emp_grade;

BEGIN
V_OT_hours := 0

Select Emp_grade into V_emp_grade from Funtom_employee
WHERE Emp_ID = :new.timesheet_emp;

Select Grade_hours into V_contracted_hours from Funtom_grade
WHERE grade_ID = V_emp_grade;

Select :new.Timesheet_hours - V_contracted_hours into V_OT_hours from Funtom_timesheet;

Select :new.Timesheet_hours - V_OT_hours into V_normal_hours;
:new.Timesheet_hours := V_normal_hours;

IF V_OT_hours != 0 THEN

INSERT INTO Funtom_timesheet(Timesheet_hours)
VALUES (V_OT_hours)
WHERE timesheet_emp = :new.timesheet_emp;

END IF

End;
/
```

Comment: I think there is a missing link to filter the "Funtom_grade" table. The first select in your trigger will produce an error because it returns all the rows from "Funtom_grade"  and attempts to insert it into the variable V_contracted_hours.

Comment: No. You should never put business logic in a trigger.

Comment: You're right you've made me realise a lot of errors I've edited the code, and I think i've corrected them now but I can't be sure because I'm completely new to this and a n00b. Can someone please help? I've added the filter/link with a where clause

Comment: Hmmm, you have an ON INSERT trigger that inserts a new row into the same table. That isn't going to work. Possibly you mean to update a value in the triggering row?

Comment: OK.  You have a trigger.  I assume when you cause the trigger to fire that you're getting errors.  I see a number of errors but it's always helpful to include that in your question.

Comment: Get rid of the V_ prefix in the variable names: if you need to use the variables in a SQL statement, namespace them with the name of the trigger: WHERE grade_ID = trg_timesheet_hours.emp_grade

Comment: It would also be helpful to show us exactly what you want to happen (run this `insert` statement, end up with this result, etc.).  I would guess that you want to put the overtime hours in `:new.timesheet_ot` so that you end up with one row that has the regular and overtime hours in two separate columns rather than having two separate rows, one with regular hours in `timesheet_hours` and one with overtime hours in `timesheet_hours`.  What is `timesheet_wc`?  Is that supposed to be the total number of hours worked?

Comment: == is not a valid operator.

Comment: == edited, question further edited to include more information

Comment: Nobody can help? I wish my oralce would work so I could test it ...